# My phaseListener does not work

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a PhaseListener and does not work. But in the computer of my co-worker if it works.

I use netbeans 6.8 With Glassfish 2.1 and Windows 32 bits

The PhaseListener:

```
package mx.udg.cgti.seguridad.listener;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import mx.udg.cgti.seguridadcore.negocio.ProcesosCNLocal;

public class SeguridadCorePhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    public SeguridadCorePhaseListener() {
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent pe) {
        System.out.println("beforePhase");
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent pe) {
        System.out.println("afterPhase");
        if (pe.getPhaseId().equals(PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW)) {

            if (pe.getFacesContext() != null) {

                String pagina = pe.getFacesContext().getViewRoot().getViewId();
                if (!"/Inicio.xhtml".equalsIgnoreCase(pagina) && !"/Login.xhtml".equalsIgnoreCase(pagina) && pagina.contains(".xhtml")) {
                    loggedIn();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void loggedIn() {
        String pagina = "";
        Long token = obtenToken();
        if (token != null) {
            String result = "";
            result = lookupProcesosCNLocal().getSesionActiva(token);
            if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
                result = null;
            }
 //           System.out.println("RESULT " + result);
            if (result == null) {
                pagina = new String("sessionTimeout");
            }
        } else {
            pagina = new String("sinSession");
        }
 //       System.out.println(" PAGINA :- " + pagina + " TOKEN " + token);
        if (!pagina.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
 //          System.out.println("REGLAS DE NAVEGACION TRABAJANDO HACIA  " + pagina);
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            NavigationHandler nh = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            nh.handleNavigation(fc, null, pagina);
            fc.renderResponse();
        }

    }

    private Long obtenToken() {
        Long token = null;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        Object t = request.getAttribute("token");
        if (t == null) {
            Object obj=null;
            if(session != null){
                obj = session.getAttribute("token");
                if(obj == null){
                    obj = request.getParameter("token");
                }
            }else{
                obj = request.getParameter("token");
            }
            if (obj != null) {
                if (obj != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(obj.toString())) {
                    token = Long.parseLong(obj.toString());
                }
            }
        } else {
            token = Long.parseLong(t.toString());
        }
        if (token != null) {
            request.setAttribute("token", token);
            if(session == null){
                session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
            }
            session.setAttribute("token", token);
        }
        return token;
    }

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;
    }

    private ProcesosCNLocal lookupProcesosCNLocal() {
        try {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (ProcesosCNLocal) c.lookup("java:comp/env/ProcesosCN");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }

}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>logear</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/Login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect>1</redirect>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>sessionTimeout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/LoginError.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>sinSession</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/LoginError.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>    
    <application>
        <message-bundle>
            mx.udg.cgti.seguridad.boundle.MiBoundle
        </message-bundle>
    </application>
    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>mx.udg.cgti.seguridad.listener.SeguridadCorePhaseListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
    <validator>
        <validator-id>validaComboRequerido</validator-id>
        <validator-class>mx.udg.cgti.seguridad.validator.ValidaComboRequerido</validator-class>
    </validator>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>tipoUsuario</converter-id>
        <converter-class>mx.udg.cgti.ln.convertidor.TipoUsuarioConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>Usuario</converter-id>
        <converter-class>mx.udg.cgti.ln.convertidor.UsuarioConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>Rol</converter-id>
        <converter-class>mx.udg.cgti.ln.convertidor.RolConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>Permiso</converter-id>
        <converter-class>mx.udg.cgti.ln.convertidor.PermisoConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>UnidadOrganizacional</converter-id>
        <converter-class>mx.udg.cgti.ln.convertidor.UnidadOrganizacionalConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>

</faces-config>
```

Comment: Please elaborate "does not work" in more detail. What are the symptoms? What do you see in server logs?

Comment: ok. In theory the listener must allow or deny access to a user.
The listener simply passes all users have permission or not, we tried putting the function 'System.out.println' in the methods 'beforePhase' and 'afterPhase' to see if printed on console. but my computer is not showing the messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you've another version of exactly the same class somewhere in the classpath which got precedence in classloading over the one included in the WAR.

That can be inside the `/lib` folder of the server itself, or inside the `/lib` or `/lib/ext` folders of the installed JRE which is used by the server.

Comment: Thank you. I change the order of jar files in the properties of my project and now works correctly.